# Some Users are missing in People from Active Directory

Tags: office-365, active-directory, azure

I am checking Directory in people view in my office 365 application. I am also checking my Azure Active Directory for all user list. When I compare this two, Most of the users are there in Directory. I've attached screenshot for both. But, some of the users which are in Azure AD not visible in Directory.
I don't know why is it happening. I asked to my Senior about the same. He explained me that this users are not synch with Sharepoint. Is it correct? where I can check, which users are sync with Azuredb and Sharepoint?

[image]
[image]

As you can see Adam Kaminicki is there in AD, but Its not visible in Directory List. I am new to sharepoint, so I am trying to explain as much as possible

Comment: Are you synchronizing the Active Directory data from an on premise Active Directory to Azure Active Directory?

Comment: No. I don't have on-premise Active Directory. What I have is only office 365 and Azure AD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"People" will show only those users who have been assigned "Exchange Online" license. It is possible to add Users to your Office 365 without giving them any of the Office 365 subscription, except "Mobile Device Management for Office 365" which is mandatory. And any user you add through Office 365 also gets added into Azure AD.